# Almost sure convergence (correctness of an argument)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Is this statement correct?
If $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s} c$, where $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables and $c$ is a constant, then we can conclude that since almost sure convergence implies on convergence in distribution

$$X_n \xrightarrow{d} c$$

Therefore,

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(X_n<t)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(c<t) = \begin{cases}
1 & c< t\\
0 & c \geq t\end{cases}$

Comment: Be careful in the case $t=c$. **Example:** If $X_n=c-1/n$ for each $n$, then $P(X_n<c)=1$ for each $n$, but the limit function you propose vanishes when $t=c$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins   Is this the only problem? The $X_n$ is deterministic?